# MVC Bootstrap LogOff

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to insert the MVC logoutForm or functianlity into a .js file?

I have a check to see if the user is logged with in the /View/Shared/_layout.cshtml page whis is as follows:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapped")
} else {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
}
```

bootstrap.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/docs.css" type="text/css" media="screen">');
    $('body').prepend('<div id="panel"><div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="advanced"><span class="trigger"><strong></strong><em></em></span><div class="navbar-inner"><div class="container"><button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-top-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><div class="nav-collapse collapse nav-top-collapse"><ul class="nav"><li class="home"><a href="/" title="Home"><img src="/Images/tm_home.png" alt="Home"></a></li><li class=""><a href="/Home/Help" title="Help">Help</a></li><li><a href="/Account/Register" title="Register">Register</a></li><li class=""><a href="/Account/Login" title="Login">Login</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>');
});
```

bootstrapped.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/docs.css" type="text/css" media="screen">');
$('body').prepend('<div id="panel"><div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="advanced"><span class="trigger"><strong></strong><em></em></span><div class="navbar-inner"><div class="container"><button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-top-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><div class="nav-collapse collapse nav-top-collapse"><ul class="nav"><li class="home"><a href="/" title="Home"><img src="/Images/tm_home.png" alt="Home"></a></li><li class=""><a href="/Home/Help" title="Help">Help</a></li><li class=""><a href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">Manage</a></li><li class=""><a href="somethinghere" title="Logout">Logout</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>');
});
```

I notice that in the original WebApplication1 MVC project was a /View/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml which contained the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })

<li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
```

I would like to get this functianlity into the boostrapped.js file if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: any reason why you are prepending pretty much static html using javascript instead of just placing raw HTML in your views? As for your question - you'd probably need to define a form with id=logoutForm and action=yourLogoutAction and then prepend that form along with your last code snippet to the body. But I just can't fathom why you would want to do that? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ideally I want to create a dynamic bootstrap.js and remove the `@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` from the _layout page, but don't know how to do it.